# Transferring Minecraft worlds using a thumb drive

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues

So recently, my long-term laptop died from a fried motherboard. On that laptop, I had a multitude of *Minecraft* worlds that I may have spent hundreds of hours on.

When my laptop died, I decided to get a new one and transfer all the data off of my last laptop to a thumb drive. I plugged it in to my new computer and have spent the last hour trying to find and import my *Minecraft* worlds.

Do any of you know how I can save my *Minecraft* worlds?

Details:

- Thumb drive: SanDisk USB 3.0
- *Minecraft*: Windows Bedrock Edition

If this question is too tech-focused, please suggest another place where I can find help.

Comment: Welcome! Knowing your Windows version may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your Minecraft Bedrock worlds in a folder called "*minecraftWorlds.*"

This is where that folder *should* be on your Thumb Drive if you have Windows files on there too, C:\Users\{**YOUR-NAME**}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_{**Jumbled-Letters**}\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds

There you should find folders with jumbled letters and numbers, move those onto your new Minecraft worlds folder on your new PC. You may not be able to find the new worlds folder if you haven't created a world on your new PC yet.